# PostgreSQL: restoring table from sql using psql return 'ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer'

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I trying to restore sql dump that looks like this:

```
COPY table_name (id, oauth_id, foo, bar) FROM stdin;
  1 142 \N  xxxxxxx
  2 142 \N  yyyyyyy
  <dozen similar lines>
```

last line in this dump: `\.`

command to restore:

`psql < table.sql`

or

`psql --file=dump.sql`

`\d+ table_name`:

```
                         Table "public.table_name"
       Column        |         Type          |                                Modifiers                                | Storage  | Stats target | Description
---------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                  | integer               | not null default nextval('connected_table_name_id_seq'::regclass)       | plain    |              |
 oauth_id            | integer               | not null                                                                | plain    |              |
 foo                 | character varying     |                                                                         | extended |              |
 bar                 | character varying     |                                                                         | extended |              |
```

Looks sadly that standard method for backup and rollback does not work :(

Version of the `psql`: 9.5.4, version of the server: 9.5.2

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the `create table` statements for the table in question

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name added

Comment: @VaoTsun yes, 'ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer'

Comment: Is there a _real_ tab character (ascii: 9) between the column values in the data?

Comment: `1 142 \N  xxxxxxx \N` is five columns, and `(id, oauth_id, foo, bar)` only four

Comment: @VaoTsun thank you, this is my typo in question

Comment: if you are typing, then mind that chr(9) the default delimiter does not like copy paste

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are right about tab character! I just copied content for one table from the original dump to another file - please post this as an answer so I can accept it.